# Ruby: Looping through timestamps and jumping back in the loop - optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, query-optimization

We have a database table in Ruby on Rails / Postgres with up to 100.000 weather data points spanning years, by the hour:

```
01/01/1999 00:00
01/01/1999 01:00
...
01/01/2000 00:00
```

The dates are saved in a `datetime` variable called `timestamp`.

We are iterating `weather_data` and sometimes we need to jump back 1-3 hours, to check again different conditions.

Then we have multiple **activities** that each run for 1-6 hours, depending on if the weather is good enough, or if they need to wait until the weather gets better.

The user can select which day of year to start the check, but it will check from that day, for every year in the database.

If the user selects '3 April 1997' it should run all the activities from that date and see how long all the activities should take.

It should then repeat that process for '3 April 1998', and 1999 and all the available years in the `weather_data`

Some activities might take 2 hours, but they need to know the weather 4 hours in advance, even though the next activity can start after 2 hours. So there is a bit of overlap. I was hoping to solve that with variables but could not figure that out, hence I thought about 'jumping' back and forth in the loop.

Simplified example:

```rb
# Collect all the years
the_years = weather_data.map { |y| y.timestamp.year }.uniq

the_years.each do |year|
  start_date = DateTime.new(year, user_input.month, user_input.day)

  # We could have ~100 activities
  activities.each do |activity|
    consecutive_good_weather_hours = 0

    weather_data.where("timestamp >= ?", start_date).each do |point|
      start_date += 1.hour

      # checking if point.wind_speed > activity.wind_speed etc.
      if weather_is_good
        # ...
        consecutive_good_weather_hours += 1

        # if this activity needs 3 hours of good weather, and we have 2/3
        # we go to the next data point, to check the next hour.

        # go to next activity if all criteria is met
        if activity_finished
          # if this activity was 3 hours long, but we were checking 2
          # hours extra into the future, we need to 'jump back' 2 hours 
          # where the next activity should start, a bit of overlap

          start_date -= 2.hours
          break
        end
      else
        # bad weather, reset counter, and go to next weather hour
        # try again to find x many hours of consecutive good weather
        consecutive_good_weather_hours = 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How optimal is this?

It looks like we are doing a new SQL query 300 times loading the ~100k dataset (while it shrinks a bit every time).

Instead of calling `.where` all the time, could we 'jump' 3 steps backwards in the loop? If yes, how?

**EDIT 1**

We replaced the `weather_data.where("timestamp >= ?", start_date).each do |point|` with the following:

```
while true
  point = weather_data.find_by_timestamp(year_start_date)
```

We also tried copying `weather_data` into an array with the `.to_a` (outside all the loops), and then do the following:

```
while true
  point = data_array.find { |i| i.timestamp == year_start_date }
```

But it turned out to be slower, see benchmarks.

Benchmark on 20k data points and 4 activities:

```
|   Option          | points |  ms  | Allocations |
|-------------------|--------|------|-------------|
| where             |   20k  | 3028 |   5931134   |
| find_by_timestamp |   20k  | 1101 |    725407   |
| data_array.find   |   20k  | 1304 |   1393532   |
```

I thought the `find_by_timestamp` would be slower then the `array.find`  because it would do a `SELECT` on every point, but it looks like it's the fastest of the 3.

We are using Heroku and our 1GB instance runs out of memory on bigger datasets.

Comment: hashes should be faster, but still that isn't your real problem here, this could be solved with memoization, you should be asking for each point between start_date and one hour, do your calculations and save them into a Hash table, then before asking the query check the hash and results instead, if the value isn't present check the query, watch this video, it should give you a good start point https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8Xa2BitN3I, you are currently doing something like O(n!) time when if I'm getting this right it should be done in O(n) time, or accordingly to your benchmarks ~3s

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not optimal at all. Even just with what you've provided (really wierd "algorithm", tbh), it's clear you're constantly re-fetching the same rows of data over and over.

A demonstration using a simplified dataset:

```
dataset = (0..9).to_a

start_index = 8

5.times do
  queried = dataset.select { |d| d >= start_index } # same as your WHERE clause, in principle
  p queried
  queried.each do |idx|
    if idx.even?
      start_index -= 3
      break
    else
      start_index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

will print:

```rb
[8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

See how it's just constantly re-fetching the same values over and over? `[8, 9]`, `[..., 8, 9]`, etc

For anything more meaningful, you'll have to explain what `something` and `update variables` are doing. Depending on what you're trying to do, your computation could be accomplished in a single query instead.

### Update for the updated question

You've fundamentally got a non-trivial scheduling and search problem going on here, and to be honest: to really solve this problem well, you'll need to learn a lot about scheduling and search algorithms, both of which are out of scope for a StackOverflow question.

At the minimum, I'll suggest two things that can still vastly improve this brute-force solution:

#### Model "Activity Time Windows"

Successively incrementing `start_date` and periodically "jumping back" is extremely awkward and is a sign that it isn't a good model of the problem.

Instead, think of an "Activity Time Window" with a beginning and end. You're "sliding the window forward in time" trying to find somewhere that fits. Whether you find a slot or not, you never "jump back from the end" because the window only moves forward, and you can get `time_window.beginning` whenever you need it.

#### Don't Refetch Data

I/O (like db query) is 1-10 orders of magnitude slower than data processing. Re-fetching is a HUGE waste of time.

Notice your `start_date` *never* moves backwards (we're using time windows now), and you'll see that your very first `weather_data.where("timestamp >= ?", start_date)` call is going to be a superset of all subsequent calls. If you're going to query for all the data the very first time anyways, don't re-fetch it again later.

Comment: Thanks, I added more context, but trying to keep it simple. I thought less people would want to help if the example was too long!

Comment: yeah, I was thinking the same, is looking like a memorization problem

Comment: Updated, hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If it's only 100k records it should be possible load everything into memory.

If your dataset does not have missing records (e.g. jumps from 1am to 3am without 2am) you could just look them up with an array.

```rb
# convert to array for lookup
records = weather_data.where("timestamp >= ?", start_date).to_a

index = 0
while index < 300 
  record = records[index]
  if something
    # update variables
    index -= 3
    break
  else
    index += 1 # sometimes we jump further
  end
end
```

If it's too big to load into memory you can iterate over it in groups.